# How can SASS help me develop responsive web designs?

Tags: css, sass

I have been designing with CSS for years, but I am only just now learning how to use SASS. This is very much a beginner question, so please bear with me.

The reason I started looking into SASS was because I wanted to develop a responsive web design, but was hoping there was a better way to do it than manually make different style sheets for every screen size.

I believe that in principle, a CSS preprossesor like SASS should help with this issue... but at the moment I don't understand how.

If I have a div with the id `#squishable`, and on large screens I want it to have a width of 1000 pixels, and on small screens a width of 100 pixels, but a red background in both cases, I think I would do something like this:

```css
$color = red;

#squishable {
    backgorundcolor: $color;
}

@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px) {

    #squishable {
        width:100px;
    }
}

@media only screen
and (min-width : 1824px) {
    #squishable {
        width:1000px;
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure this approach is in much of an advantage over just using CSS. Maybe as an example, it's too simplistic. But, in any case, I don't see exactly what I would be doing differently with SASS to make it easier to code for a responsive web design. Is this all there is to it?

Can someone help me get over this conceptual hurdle and let me know how I take advantage of SASS to create elements that are responsive? Hopefully with a simple example similar to what I've got above?

Answer (score 3):

You can absolutely improve your workflow further!

Using SASS `@mixin`, `@include`, `@content` and regular `variables` you can setup an environment where you create your media queries "inline", or inside of your regular selectors if you will.

---

### This is my mixin for media queries:

*(never mind the stupid variable names and placeholder breakpoints)*

```
// Breakpoints
$mq-tiny:   5em;
$mq-small:  10em;
$mq-medium: 15em;
$mq-large:  20em;
$mq-huge:   25em;
$mq-crazy:  30em;

@mixin mq($size, $direction: min-width, $media-type: only all) {
  @if      $size == tiny   { @media #{$media-type} and (#{$direction}: $mq-tiny)   { @content; } }
  @else if $size == small  { @media #{$media-type} and (#{$direction}: $mq-small)  { @content; } }
  @else if $size == medium { @media #{$media-type} and (#{$direction}: $mq-medium) { @content; } }
  @else if $size == large  { @media #{$media-type} and (#{$direction}: $mq-large)  { @content; } }
  @else if $size == huge   { @media #{$media-type} and (#{$direction}: $mq-huge)   { @content; } }
  @else if $size == crazy  { @media #{$media-type} and (#{$direction}: $mq-crazy)  { @content; } }
  @else                    { @media #{$media-type} and (#{$direction}: $size)      { @content; } }
}
```

### And here's an example of how it can be used:

**SCSS:**

```
.selector {
  width: 100px;

  @include mq(large) {
    width: 1000px;
  }
}
```

**CSS output:**

```
.selector {
  width: 100px
}

@media only all and (min-width: 20em) {
  .selector {
    width: 1000px
  }
}
```

---

Take note that you don't need to use a variable name for the width. You can pass `1000px` instead of `large` if you want to.

You may also have noticed the optional arguments in the `@mixin`; `$direction` and `$media-type`. These arguments default to `min-width` and `only all` respectively, but if you pass them through the `@include` they'll change for that specific element only.

### Example with other arguments:

**SCSS:**

```
.selector {
  @include mq(1000px, min-height) {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

**CSS output:**

```
@media only all and (min-height: 1000px) {
  .selector {
    width: 100px
  }
}
```

---

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**
[Here's a pen](http://codepen.io/Mest/pen/mAhxv?editors=110) if you want to play around with it.

Comment: Nice answer, looks like I might have a go at it even if I'm a "hardcoder" when it comes to CSS.

Answer (score 1):

To increase maintainability of your code you can use variables to define media queries breakpoints:

```
// define breakpoints
$small-screen: 321px;
$large-screen: 1824px;

$small: "only screen and (min-width:"#{$small-screen}")";
$large: "only screen and (min-width:"#{$large-screen}")";
// and so on...


// now you can esely manipulate with your media breakpoints
@media #{$small} {
    ...
}

@media #{$large} {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend you develop your SAAS css style import bootstrap framework, it will save you much time at responsive web designs

More detailed information please see this link:
http://pivotallabs.com/sass-with-bootstrap/

Comment: Thanks your advise. I will post a link that contains more detailed information